# Why "в современное время" and not "в современном времени"?

Tags: предлоги

At least according to some native speakers...

(since **время** is neuter).

Is **"в современное время"** considered to be the prepositional case?

Comment: По-моему, так вообще не говорят. Since "со*време*нное" contains "время" itself, получается "масло масляное" (this results a tautology) :)

Comment: It's better to say "в нынешнее время", "в настоящее время" (nowadays); or "в последнее время" (recently). Also "в наше время" is used, but it may refer both to current times or to old times based on context.

Comment: As a novice, I am interested in understanding why **время** does not decline to reflect the prepositional case, more than in which adjective would be preferable. As for the adjective, I see why **современный** would sound funny to some people with a linguistic mind but I guess like in other languages the word is common enough for people to overlook the etymology, that is, to use the same adjective for "modern computers" and "modern modes".

Comment: **Время** actually *do* decline to reflect the prepositional case :) If you try to find some examples, look at phrases [`в античном времени`](https://www.google.ru/search?num=30&biw=1278&bih=715&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22&oq=%22%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22)

Comment: *современное время* sounds pretty much as weird as "contemporary time"

Comment: @rapt It is accusative, that's why you don't see any change. As for the expression itself, well, it is rather uncommon. I might have actually encountered it but I don't remember it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's accusative.

*В + acc.* means "at a certain time period": *в войну, в перестройку* "during the war, during the perestroika", or "once in a certain time period": *три раза в час* "three times per hour".

In the modern language the first construct is replaced with *в +  prep.*, *на + prep.* or *inst.* with several words: *в году, на неделе, осенью*. You have to learn the usage for each word, same as you have learn to use different prepositions for "in the summer, on Friday, at seven o'clock" in English.

*В год, в неделю, в осень* are still valid, though they sound archaic, unless they have a non-agreeing modifier: *в прошлом году* but *в год Дракона*.

Comment: [I quote] *"the first construct is often replaced with в + prep., на + prep."* Did you mean, as bare-bones example,  `"в прошлый год" <=> "в прошлом году"`, `"в прошлую неделю" <=> "на прошлой неделе"`?

Comment: @Avtokod: yes, exactly

Comment: As you say, *"В год" ... are still valid, though they sound archaic.* Why "it sound arhaic" as opposite to "в году"? It doesn't seem like it's true. -->

Comment: --> Нere are [**the results from Google books**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B2+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%2C+%D0%B2+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%92%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B2%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%92%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Avtokod you ever heard of context? Your search includes constructs like "три раза в год" which are not archaic. I was talking of constructs like *церковь построена в год 2015 от рождества Христова* (rather than *… в  2015 году…*)

Comment: ok, now, what do we say about that? `церковь построили в год Рождества Христова; создано в год моего рождения/90-летия; в год и 2 месяца ребёнок умеет ..., в год и три он еще не говорил; она родилась: в год Стрельца, в годы Великой Отечественной войны, в год выборов в Думу, в год переезда в Москву; заветы, данные самому себе в годы юношества; каждому причитается в год по 1000 рублей, он прибавляет в год по 3 см; вопрос надеялись решить в год, но всё тянулось уже два года; война начнётся в год, месяц и число, назначенные нашим фюрером; из года в год.` \*Sigh\* :) Does anybody need more input?

Comment: @Quassnoi is “в prep времени” then the modern way to speak? I do not think the people whom I have heard saying “в acc время” had any intention to use archaic language. Also answers like the one by Anixx make another distinction.

Comment: @rapt: there are several words (*год*, _век_, _месяц_ and probably several others) which are used in _в + prep._ in the modern language. _время_ is not one of them.

Answer (score 5):

There is a standard pattern for time attribution:

> **`в/во ... время`**, **accusative**,
>   where `...` can be: `то, его, своё, всякое, военное, тёплое,..` (i. e. 'determiners' (possessives), adjectives)
>   Also in plural: `в/во ... времена`

It seems obvious (though I cannot know really 'why', it should be questioned those who speak so) this pattern is awkwardly used with `современный`. (It looks unRussian really to me.) If one wants to use `современный` for time attribution it’d be better to say `в современную эпоху`, `в современности`, `в современный исторический момент`, `в современном мире` what is generally not colloquial.

Concerning **the prepositional case**.
I can remember now just two cases when I could expect the use of `"в/во ... времени"` construction *for indicating 'when'*. <kbd>(But, *I suppose*, in that construction 'time' is better interpreted as a medium, space, that is really *'**where** in time'*: `в пространстве-времени` *(in space-time)*.)</kbd> The cases:

- grammatical: `в настоящем/прошлом/будущем времени`,
- epochal: `‘В каком времени ты живёшь?’` *(What is a time realm you are dwelling in?)* where `‘В`<del>`современном`</del>`настоящем [времени]’` could be an answer,
   `в том времени` referring to, e. g., `во времена ГУЛАГа` *(in the era of the GULAG)*…
   (i. e. ‘time’ conceived as the time of a different world)

Indeed I don’t have an opportunity to investigate the question and can miss something here. Though hopefully it’s enough for your 'why'.

Comment: Just **two** cases of using `"в/во ... времени"`? ))))

Comment: more examples with the prepositional case: `изменение во времени` _(variation over time)_, `путешествие во времени` _(time journey)_, `разница во времени` _(time difference)_  ...

Comment: @delete Wonderful answer

Answer (score 2):

While people have pointed you that *современное время* is a tautology, I will avoid this issue and concentrate on the case.

*в современное время* : currently, nowadays

*в современном времени* : inside the current time. Well, maybe it is from a sci-fi fiction about a time machine and time branches?

Comment: Object in the Accusative will always be a spot in the time line. It's language invariant. For English, this is the situation in which they would use "at" when referring to a location. Whereas Prepositional `in = в` can connote enclosure as inside. *+1* for the accurate comparison )

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос содержит ложную дихотомию. Ответ должен это учитывать. 
Как вообще такой вопрос  мог возникнуть?

1. Дано три слова <kbd>в</kbd>, <kbd>современный</kbd>, <kbd>время</kbd>. Необходимо построить согласованное сочетание слов в предложном падеже. Некто получил два варианта, **Z** и **Y**. Естественно, у него возникли два правомерных вопроса:
   а) они взаимозаменяемы? и
   б) тот вопрос-дихотомия, который и оказался в OP: *Why **Z** and not **Y**?*
2. Далее еще хуже. Наш Некто не увидел, что он получил сочетания слов в двух разных падежах **Z**=acc и **Y**=prep, и он заключает, основываясь на ложном положении о существовании одновременно **Z** и **Y**, как различных форм в одном падеже (т.е. основываясь на противоречии), что между **Z** и **Y** можно произвольно выбирать. Скажем, только **Y**. Или наоборот. Причина для такого произвола? Ну, возможно, такая: это не звучит.

   Анализируя далeе, как такая ошибка вообще могла возникнуть, в самом начале, в пункте **1.**, можно прийти к выводу, что и для генерации грамматики, и для проверки эквивалентности ее результатов, а именно **Z** и **Y**, был использован неподходящий метод, например, постановка какого-то вопроса. Скорее всего, `В ком?/в чем?`, или, что намного хуже, `когда?`

   Чтобы избежать тавтологии,  мы далее заменим прилагательное в условии пункта **1**: <kbd>в</kbd>, <kbd>прошлый</kbd>, <kbd>время</kbd>. Итак, наш Некто получил два варианта: **Z**="в прошлое время" и **Y**="в прошлом времени". Далее, наш Некто не сумел различить их вопросом `в ком?/в чем?`, заключив, что оба стоят в одном предложном падеже. А если их нельзя различить, то их можно заменять. Очевидно, что наш Некто полагался на свой собственный слух или чутьё, вместо знания жёсткой грамматики. У взрослых людей это бывает среди эмигрантов, лет через пять у них притупляется чувство родного языка, это заметно при разговоре с ними. У них появляются ошибки в речи и на письме.
3. В ответах [эту дихотомию даже поддержали](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/8861/5288), что дескать, `в + Noun_acc.` можно заменить(!) на `в + Noun_prep`. Это сопровождается примером, что такой заменой стали бы сочетания слов `"в прошлый год" <=> "в прошлом году"`, `"в прошлую неделю" <=> "на прошлой неделе".` Основанием для выбора было предложено взять категории архаичности, или устарелости. Правда, там не приводилось содержательных примеров полных предложений, с заменой винительного падежа на предложный, так что это утверждение осталось бессодержательным.

Я утверждаю, в русском языке такая замена невозможна. Поэтому здесь ложная дихотомия. Трудно представить, что такой язык вообще существует, в котором возможно в предложении грамматически выделенный "объект" заменить на грамматически выделенное "место действия".

Для желающих попробовать заменить  Винительный на Предложный в предложении, вот пример:
*"Я капнул три капли в стеклянный стакан."*
Сочетание слов в предложном падеже: *"в стеклянном стакане"*.

Ниже, на простом примере показано, как работает грамматическая связь в русском языке. И почему вопрос *"Why **Z** and not **Y**?"* является ложной дихотомией. Оба, **Z** и **Y**, правильны, сочетаются в разных падежах, и не взаимозаменяемы.

---

we shall consider examples

```
 ... потому что, потеряв веру в современное общество, ...
            ...  потеряв себя в современном обществе, ...
```

We have to get rid of these examples: *временное время, общественное общество, столичная столица, водочная водка, ...* **.**

Here we have a direct object (i.e. in the accusative case):

```
            
потеряв веру, в кого? / во что? Answer is in the Acc.
```

And here we have the place where the action is performed, for which reason it is prepositional case:

```
 потеряв себя, в ком?  / в чем?  Answer is in the Prep.
```

So, the answer is:
both cases are completely compatible with the Russian grammar. *Общество, время, эпоха, интервал, мгновение ...*, it doesn't matter, what a noun.

---

It wasn't hard to find examples of how to use this interesting word `время` )) in the prepositional case, just look at phrases
[`в античном времени`](https://www.google.ru/search?num=30&biw=1278&bih=715&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22&oq=%22%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22),
[`в прошлом времени`](https://www.google.ru/search?num=30&biw=1278&bih=715&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22&oq=%22%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22#newwindow=1&tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 1):

Both variants are incorrect: со**врем**енное **врем**я :tautology.

correctly: "в современности", "в н**ы**нешнее время", "н**ы**не" (outdated), "сейч**а**с" ("nowdays"), "в тек**у**щее время"

в [неком] времени - means some not real time period, not applicable to your actual environment (do ya need some philosophy?). some abstracted period, out of this time, may be parallel time. not current period, even you say "в этом времени" means "this time line".

в настоящем времени, в будущем времени, в прошедшем времени - grammar (not real, abstraction)

в мое время - means some period from my past (when the speaker was as young as listener is).

**в** моем **времени** - points to my time line (to my life period when it is actual), when two men from a different time met each other, and one of them say this.

Wonderful question))